# "near ")": syntax error" sqlite update

Tags: python, sqlite, update

los datos se almacenan, se muestran y se eliminan a la perfeccion pero a la hora de actualizar dichos datos me surge este error y no lo veo.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
```

> aqui  incia mi db

```py
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def conexionBBDDSueldos ():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect ("Sueldos")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor ()
    
    try:
        miCursor.execute ('''
                CREATE TABLE TablaSueldos (
                ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MONTO1 VARCHAR (50), MONTO2 VARCHAR (50), MONTO3 VARCHAR (50), MONTO4 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO5 VARCHAR (50), MONTO6 VARCHAR (50), MONTO7 VARCHAR (50), MONTO8 VARCHAR (50), MONTO9 VARCHAR (50), MONTO10 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO11 VARCHAR (50), MONTO12 VARCHAR (50), MONTO13 VARCHAR (50), MONTO14 VARCHAR (50), MONTO15 VARCHAR (50), MONTO16 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO17 VARCHAR (50), MONTO18 VARCHAR (50), MONTO19 VARCHAR (50), MONTO20 VARCHAR (50), MONTO21 VARCHAR (50), MONTO22 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO23 VARCHAR (50), MONTO24 VARCHAR (50), MONTO25 VARCHAR (50), MONTO26 VARCHAR (50), MONTO27 VARCHAR (50), MONTO28 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO29 VARCHAR (50), MONTO30 VARCHAR (50), MONTO31 VARCHAR (50), MONTO32 VARCHAR (50), MONTO33 VARCHAR (50), MONTO34 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO35 VARCHAR (50), MONTO36 VARCHAR (50), MONTO37 VARCHAR (50), MONTO38 VARCHAR (50), MONTO39 VARCHAR (50), MONTO40 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO41 VARCHAR (50), MONTO42 VARCHAR (50), MONTO43 VARCHAR (50), MONTO44 VARCHAR (50), MONTO45 VARCHAR (50), MONTO46 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO47 VARCHAR (50), MONTO48 VARCHAR (50), MONTO49 VARCHAR (50), MONTO50 VARCHAR (50), MONTO51 VARCHAR (50), MONTO52 VARCHAR (50),
                MONTO53 VARCHAR (50), MONTO54 VARCHAR (50), MONTO55 VARCHAR (50), MONTO56 VARCHAR (50), MAX_AUTORIDAD VARCHAR (50), DIREC_EN_LINEA VARCHAR (50),
                JEFE_DE_DIVICION VARCHAR (50), COOR_DE_AREA VARCHAR (50))
                ''')

        messagebox.showinfo ("BBDD", "BBDD creada con éxito")
    except:
        messagebox.showwarning ("¡Atención!", "La BBDD ya existe")
```

> aqui termina la db hay un boton en la interface que la crea (es momentanio).

> Y desde aqui estan los problemas

```py
#--------------------------DEFINICIONES----------------------------------------

def guardar():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect ("Sueldos")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor ()
    datos = monto1.get (), monto2.get (), monto3.get (), monto4.get (), monto5.get (), monto6.get (), monto7.get (), monto8.get (),\
     monto9.get (), monto10.get (), monto11.get (), monto12.get (), monto13.get (), monto14.get (), monto15.get (), monto16.get (),\
     monto17.get (), monto18.get (), monto19.get (), monto20.get (), monto21.get (), monto22.get (), monto23.get (), monto24.get (),\
     monto25.get (), monto26.get (), monto27.get (), monto28.get (), monto29.get (), monto30.get (), monto31.get (), monto32.get (),\
     monto33.get (), monto34.get (), monto35.get (), monto36.get (), monto37.get (), monto38.get (), monto39.get (), monto40.get (),\
     monto41.get (), monto42.get (), monto43.get (), monto44.get (), monto45.get (), monto46.get (), monto47.get (), monto48.get (),\
     monto49.get (), monto50.get (), monto51.get (), monto52.get (), monto53.get (), monto54.get (), monto55.get (), monto56.get (),\
     montoMaxAutoridad.get(), montoDirecEnLinea.get(), montoJefeDeDivision.get(), montoCoordDeArea.get()
    miCursor.execute ("INSERT INTO TablaSueldos VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (datos))
    miConexion.commit ()

    messagebox.showinfo ("BBDD", "Registro Guardado con Exito.")

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def leer ():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect ("Sueldos")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor ()
    miCursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM TablaSueldos WHERE ID = " + miID.get ())
    elUsuario = miCursor.fetchall ()
    
    for usuario in elUsuario:
        miID.set([0]), monto1.set (usuario[1]), monto2.set (usuario[2]), monto3.set (usuario[3]), monto4.set (usuario[4]), monto5.set (usuario[5]), monto6.set (usuario[6]), monto7.set (usuario[7]), monto8.set (usuario[8]),\
     monto9.set (usuario[9]), monto10.set (usuario[10]), monto11.set (usuario[11]), monto12.set (usuario[12]), monto13.set (usuario[13]), monto14.set (usuario[14]), monto15.set (usuario[15]), monto16.set (usuario[16]),\
     monto17.set (usuario[17]), monto18.set (usuario[18]), monto19.set (usuario[19]), monto20.set (usuario[20]), monto21.set (usuario[21]), monto22.set (usuario[22]), monto23.set (usuario[23]), monto24.set (usuario[24]),\
     monto25.set (usuario[25]), monto26.set (usuario[26]), monto27.set (usuario[27]), monto28.set (usuario[28]), monto29.set (usuario[29]), monto30.set (usuario[30]), monto31.set (usuario[31]), monto32.set (usuario[32]),\
     monto33.set (usuario[33]), monto34.set (usuario[34]), monto35.set (usuario[35]), monto36.set (usuario[36]), monto37.set (usuario[37]), monto38.set (usuario[38]), monto39.set (usuario[39]), monto40.set (usuario[40]),\
     monto41.set (usuario[41]), monto42.set (usuario[42]), monto43.set (usuario[43]), monto44.set (usuario[44]), monto45.set (usuario[45]), monto46.set (usuario[46]), monto47.set (usuario[47]), monto48.set (usuario[48]),\
     monto49.set (usuario[49]), monto50.set (usuario[50]), monto51.set (usuario[51]), monto52.set (usuario[52]), monto53.set (usuario[53]), monto54.set (usuario[54]), monto55.set (usuario[55]), monto56.set (usuario[56]),\
     montoMaxAutoridad.set(usuario[57]), montoDirecEnLinea.set(usuario[58]), montoJefeDeDivision.set(usuario[59]), montoCoordDeArea.set(usuario[60])
    miConexion.commit ()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def Actualizar ():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect ("Sueldos")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor ()
    #Datos = monto1.get(),monto2.get(),monto3.get(),monto4.get(),monto5.get(),monto6.get(),monto7.get(),monto8.get(),monto9.get(),monto10.get(),monto11.get(),monto12.get(),monto13.get(),monto14.get(),monto15.get(),monto16.get(),monto17.get(),monto18.get(),monto19.get(),monto20.get(),monto21.get(),monto22.get(),monto23.get(),monto24.get(),monto25.get(),monto26.get(),monto27.get(),monto28.get(),monto29.get(),monto30.get(),monto31.get(),monto32.get(),monto33.get(),monto34.get(),monto35.get(),monto36.get(),monto37.get(),monto38.get(),monto39.get(),monto40.get(),monto41.get(),monto42.get(),monto43.get(),monto44.get(),monto45.get(),monto46.get(),monto47.get(),monto48.get(),monto49.get(),monto50.get(),monto51.get(),monto52.get(),monto53.get(),monto54.get(),monto55.get(),monto56.get(),montoMaxAutoridad.get(),montoDirecEnLinea.get(),montoJefeDeDivision.get(),montoCoordDeArea.get()
    miCursor.execute ("UPDATE TablaSueldos SET 'MONTO1'=?, 'MONTO2'=?, 'MONTO3'=?, 'MONTO4'=?, 'MONTO5'=?, 'MONTO6'=?, 'MONTO7'=?, 'MONTO8'=?, 'MONTO9'=?, 'MONTO10'=?, 'MONTO11'=?, 'MONTO12'=?, 'MONTO13'=?, 'MONTO14'=?, 'MONTO15'=?, 'MONTO16'=?, 'MONTO17'=?, 'MONTO18'=?, 'MONTO19'=?, 'MONTO20'=?, 'MONTO21'=?, 'MONTO22'=?, 'MONTO23'=?, 'MONTO24'=?, 'MONTO25'=?, 'MONTO26'=?, 'MONTO27'=?, 'MONTO28'=?, 'MONTO29'=?, 'MONTO30'=?, 'MONTO31'=?, 'MONTO32'=?, 'MONTO33'=?, 'MONTO34'=?, 'MONTO35'=?, 'MONTO36'=?, 'MONTO37'=?, 'MONTO38'=?, 'MONTO39'=?, 'MONTO40'=?, 'MONTO41'=?, 'MONTO42'=?, 'MONTO43'=?, 'MONTO44'=?, 'MONTO45'=?, 'MONTO46'=?, 'MONTO47'=?, 'MONTO48'=?, 'MONTO49'=?, 'MONTO50'=?, 'MONTO51'=?, 'MONTO52'=?, 'MONTO53'=?, 'MONTO54'=?, 'MONTO55'=?, 'MONTO56'=?, 'MAX_AUTORIDAD'=?, 'DIREC_EN_LINEA'=?, 'JEFE_DE_DIVICION'=?, 'COOR_DE_AREA'=?" + " WHERE ID = " + miID.get())
    miConexion.commit ()
    messagebox.showinfo ("BBDD", "Registro Actualizado con Exito.")
```

> apartir de este punto ya es visual no tengo problemas con esto

```py
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

root = tk.Tk ()
root.title ("TABLA SALARIAL")
root.config (bg = "#1c1c1c")
#barraMenu = Menu (root)
#root.config (menu = barraMenu, width = 1200, height = 600)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#menuBD = Menu (barraMenu, tearoff = 0)
#menuBD.add_command (label = "Conexion con BD", command = conexionBBDDSueldos)
#menuBD.add_command (label = "Salir", command = salirAplicacion)
```

#---------------------------VARIBLES-------------------------------------------

```py
miID=StringVar()
monto1=StringVar()
monto2=StringVar()
monto3=StringVar()
monto4=StringVar()
monto5=StringVar()
monto6=StringVar()
monto7=StringVar()
monto8=StringVar()
monto9=StringVar()
monto10=StringVar()
monto11=StringVar()
monto12=StringVar()
monto13=StringVar()
monto14=StringVar()
monto15=StringVar()
monto16=StringVar()
monto17=StringVar()
monto18=StringVar()
monto19=StringVar()
monto20=StringVar()
monto21=StringVar()
monto22=StringVar()
monto23=StringVar()
monto24=StringVar()
monto25=StringVar()
monto26=StringVar()
monto27=StringVar()
monto28=StringVar()
monto29=StringVar()
monto30=StringVar()
monto31=StringVar()
monto32=StringVar()
monto33=StringVar()
monto34=StringVar()
monto35=StringVar()
monto36=StringVar()
monto37=StringVar()
monto38=StringVar()
monto39=StringVar()
monto40=StringVar()
monto41=StringVar()
monto42=StringVar()
monto43=StringVar()
monto44=StringVar()
monto45=StringVar()
monto46=StringVar()
monto47=StringVar()
monto48=StringVar()
monto49=StringVar()
monto50=StringVar()
monto51=StringVar()
monto52=StringVar()
monto53=StringVar()
monto54=StringVar()
monto55=StringVar()
monto56=StringVar()
montoMaxAutoridad=StringVar()
montoDirecEnLinea=StringVar()
montoJefeDeDivision=StringVar()
montoCoordDeArea=StringVar()
```

> si existe una manera de no hacer esta lista varibles de esta menera seria de mucha ayuda

```py
#---------------------------ENCABEZADO-----------------------------------------

rango1Label = Label (root, text = "1", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango1Label.grid (row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango2Label = Label (root, text = "2", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango2Label.grid (row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango3Label = Label (root, text = "3", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango3Label.grid (row = 0, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango4Label = Label (root, text = "4", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango4Label.grid (row = 0, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango5Label = Label (root, text = "5", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango5Label.grid (row = 0, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango6Label = Label (root, text = "6", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango6Label.grid (row = 0, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rango7Label = Label (root, text = "7", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rango7Label.grid (row = 0, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5)

#-----------------------------RANGOS--------------------------------------------

administrativobachillerLabel = Label (root, text = "PERSONAL ADMINISTRATIVO O BACHILLER", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#bcbdbf")
administrativobachillerLabel.grid (row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan=8)

rangob1Label = Label (root, text = "B(I)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangob1Label.grid (row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rangob2Label = Label (root, text = "B(II)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangob2Label.grid (row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rangob3Label = Label (root, text = "B(III)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangob3Label.grid (row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

personalTecnicoUniversitarioLabel = Label (root, text = "PERSONAL TECNICO UNIVERSITARIO", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#bcbdbf")
personalTecnicoUniversitarioLabel.grid (row = 5, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan=8)

rangot1Label = Label (root, text = "T(I)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangot1Label.grid (row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rangot2Label = Label (root, text = "T(II)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangot2Label.grid (row = 7, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

ersonalProfecionalUniversitarioLabel = Label (root, text = "PERSONAL PROFECIONAL UNIVERSITARIO", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#bcbdbf")
ersonalProfecionalUniversitarioLabel.grid (row = 8, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan=8)

rangoP1Label = Label (root, text = "P(I)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangoP1Label.grid (row = 9, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rangoP2Label = Label (root, text = "P(II)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangoP2Label.grid (row = 10, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

rangoP3Label = Label (root, text = "P(III)", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
rangoP3Label.grid (row = 11, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

ersonalProfecionalUniversitarioLabel = Label (root, text = "ALTOS CARGOS Y DE CONFIANZA", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#bcbdbf")
ersonalProfecionalUniversitarioLabel.grid (row = 12, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, columnspan=8)

maxAutoridad = Label (root, text = "MAX. AUTORIDAD", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
maxAutoridad.grid (row = 13, column = 0, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

directorEnLinea = Label (root, text = "DIRECTOR EN LINEA", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
directorEnLinea.grid (row = 13, column = 2, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

jefesDeDivision = Label (root, text = "JEFES DE DIVISION", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
jefesDeDivision.grid (row = 13, column = 4, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

coordinadorArea = Label (root, text = "COORD. DE AREA", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
coordinadorArea.grid (row = 13, column = 6, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "B1"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto1)
cuadroMonto1B1.grid (row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto2)
cuadroMonto2B1.grid (row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto3)
cuadroMonto3B1.grid (row = 2, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto4)
cuadroMonto4B1.grid (row = 2, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto5)
cuadroMonto5B1.grid (row = 2, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto6)
cuadroMonto6B1.grid (row = 2, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7B1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto7)
cuadroMonto7B1.grid (row = 2, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "B2"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto8)
cuadroMonto1B2.grid (row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto9)
cuadroMonto2B2.grid (row = 3, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto10)
cuadroMonto3B2.grid (row = 3, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto11)
cuadroMonto4B2.grid (row = 3, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto12)
cuadroMonto5B2.grid (row = 3, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto13)
cuadroMonto6B2.grid (row = 3, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7B2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto14)
cuadroMonto7B2.grid (row = 3, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "B3"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto15)
cuadroMonto1B3.grid (row = 4, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto16)
cuadroMonto2B3.grid (row = 4, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto17)
cuadroMonto3B3.grid (row = 4, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto18)
cuadroMonto4B3.grid (row = 4, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto19)
cuadroMonto5B3.grid (row = 4, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto20)
cuadroMonto6B3.grid (row = 4, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7B3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto21)
cuadroMonto7B3.grid (row = 4, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "T1"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto22)
cuadroMonto1T1.grid (row = 6, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto23)
cuadroMonto2T1.grid (row = 6, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto24)
cuadroMonto3T1.grid (row = 6, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto25)
cuadroMonto4T1.grid (row = 6, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto26)
cuadroMonto5T1.grid (row = 6, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto27)
cuadroMonto6T1.grid (row = 6, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7T1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto28)
cuadroMonto7T1.grid (row = 6, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "T2"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto29)
cuadroMonto1T2.grid (row = 7, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto30)
cuadroMonto2T2.grid (row = 7, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto31)
cuadroMonto3T2.grid (row = 7, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto32)
cuadroMonto4T2.grid (row = 7, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto33)
cuadroMonto5T2.grid (row = 7, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto34)
cuadroMonto6T2.grid (row = 7, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7T2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto35)
cuadroMonto7T2.grid (row = 7, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "P1"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto36)
cuadroMonto1P1.grid (row = 9, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto37)
cuadroMonto2P1.grid (row = 9, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto38)
cuadroMonto3P1.grid (row = 9, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto39)
cuadroMonto4P1.grid (row = 9, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto40)
cuadroMonto5P1.grid (row = 9, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto41)
cuadroMonto6P1.grid (row = 9, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7P1 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto42)
cuadroMonto7P1.grid (row = 9, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "P2"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto43)
cuadroMonto1P2.grid (row = 10, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto44)
cuadroMonto2P2.grid (row = 10, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto45)
cuadroMonto3P2.grid (row = 10, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto46)
cuadroMonto4P2.grid (row = 10, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto47)
cuadroMonto5P2.grid (row = 10, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto48)
cuadroMonto6P2.grid (row = 10, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7P2 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto49)
cuadroMonto7P2.grid (row = 10, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------------------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "P3"----------------------------

cuadroMonto1P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto50)
cuadroMonto1P3.grid (row = 11, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto2P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto51)
cuadroMonto2P3.grid (row = 11, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto3P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto52)
cuadroMonto3P3.grid (row = 11, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto4P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto53)
cuadroMonto4P3.grid (row = 11, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto5P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto54)
cuadroMonto5P3.grid (row = 11, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto6P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto55)
cuadroMonto6P3.grid (row = 11, column = 6, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroMonto7P3 = Entry (root, textvariable = monto56)
cuadroMonto7P3.grid (row = 11, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#----------------CUADROS DE SUELDOS "ALTOS FUNCIONARIOS Y DE CONFIANZA"-----------------

cuadroMaxAutoridad = Entry (root, textvariable = montoMaxAutoridad)
cuadroMaxAutoridad.grid (row = 13, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroDirecLinea = Entry (root, textvariable = montoDirecEnLinea)
cuadroDirecLinea.grid (row = 13, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroJefeDivision = Entry (root, textvariable = montoJefeDeDivision)
cuadroJefeDivision.grid (row = 13, column = 5, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

cuadroCoordArea = Entry (root, textvariable = montoCoordDeArea)
cuadroCoordArea.grid (row = 13, column = 7, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#---------------------------------------BOTONES----------------------------------------

codigoID = Label (root, text = "ID", bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff")
codigoID.grid (row = 14, column = 2, sticky = "e", padx = 5, pady = 5)

cuadroCodigoID = Entry (root, textvariable = miID)
cuadroCodigoID.grid (row = 14, column = 3, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 1, ipady = 1)

#---------------------------------------OTROS------------------------------------------

botonVer=Button(root, text="VER", command=leer, bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff" )
botonVer.grid(row=14, column=4, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=20, ipady=1)

botonGuardar=Button(root, text="GUARDAR", command=guardar, bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff" )
botonGuardar.grid(row=14, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=20, ipady=1)

botonActualizar=Button(root, text="ACTUALIZAR", command=Actualizar, bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff" )
botonActualizar.grid(row=14, column=6, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=20, ipady=1)

#botonCancelar=Button(root, text="GUARDAR", command=guardar, bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff" )
#botonCancelar.grid(row=14, column=6, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=20, ipady=1)

botonCrearTabla=Button(root, text="DDBB", command=conexionBBDDSueldos, bg="#1c1c1c", fg="#0044ff" )
botonCrearTabla.grid(row=14, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=20, ipady=1)

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


root.mainloop()
```

> esto es en ecencia el codigo que me da problemas

Comment: Cuida los espacios cuando concatenas. Esto: `COOR_DE_AREA=?" + "WHERE ID = "` te juntará `WHERE` con el parámetro, pon un espacio antes de WHERE, de este modo: **`" WHERE ID = "`** así el parámetro quedará separado. Y, ¿esto qué significa: `,(Datos)` al final de tu sentencia?

Comment: @gbianchi me suena a Phyton, al cual conozco sólo de oídas, pero supongo que tendrá formas de concatenar mejor, como marcadores, en lugar de usar `+`. Argenis, supongo que `Datos()` representaría los valores que quieres pasar para cada monto ¿? Tu problema más que nada es de depurar el código, poniendo puntos de interrupción y revisando el valor de cada cosa o imprimiendo. Considera que por cada `?` tú tienes que pasar un valor, ¿dónde están esos valores?

Comment: ok.. hay mucho lio aca.. vamos de vuelta. En este momento no le estas pasando valores, asi que logicamente va a tirar error. Cuando le pasas valores, tira error. Podemos depurar esa consulta, con valores? podes ir probando los campos de a uno a ver en que momento tira error. asi como esta, es muy dificil decirte que esta mal, porque nadie aca se va a poner a contar campos a ver si estan todos. Otra cosa, las comillas simples eran sobre los parametros, no sobre los nombres de los campos. y aunque no los sumes, estos numeros si son numeros y van como numeros.

Comment: ah y toda la parte visual, a nostros y a tu pregunta, no le sirven. No es todo tu codigo, es el codigo que reproduce tu problema ;)

Comment: ok voy a cambiar el tipo de dato luego empiezo a depurar uno a uno y actualizo, se que la parte visual no sirve aqui pero queria que viera el diseño y el por que de tanto codigo en la db, no voy agregar mas ni menos de lo que esta hay simplemente el dia que el gobierno modifique esos montos, la idea es solo editar y ya (borrar monto viejo, colocar el nuevo y darle al boton actualizar), solo queria aclarar que esa fue mi solucion.

Comment: A ver, no conozco Phyton, pero, ¿qué hacen tus comillas simples rodeando cada nombre de columna `MONTO` y las demás columnas ¿?  Intenta tu instrucción así, quitando las comillas simples de las columnas, e incorpora el `WHERE` a tu consulta preparada, poniendo un marcador, y obteniendo su valor en `datos`
. O sea algo así: `miCursor.execute ("UPDATE TablaSueldos SET MONTO1=?,  MONTO2=?, ... completa los otros MONTO cuidando de no cometer errores ...  MAX_AUTORIDAD=?, DIREC_EN_LINEA=?, JEFE_DE_DIVICION=?, COOR_DE_AREA=? WHERE ID = ?", (Datos))`

Comment: Y, descomenta la línea donde obtienes los datos. El valor para el `ID` que usas en el `WHERE` debes obtenerlo junto con los demás datos que pasarás en parámetro: `Datos = monto1.get(), ... todos los otros monto ... , miID.get()` Si sigue sin funcionar, debes comparar que la cantidad de marcadores y sus posiciones concuerdan con lo que obtienes en `Datos` y, revisa la sintaxis, en Español División es con `S`, no sé si tienes declarada así esta columna en tu tabla: `JEFE_DE_DIVICION`, puede ser un error de ortografía nada más, pero puede convertirse en error de sintaxis.

Comment: @A.Cedano veo que no conoces python pero eres un genio, ya no tengo el error, por fin dice "Registro Actualizado con Exito.", pero........   no actualiza. -_- cuando le doy en el boton "ver" para verificar no se actualizan.

Comment: Revisa lo que hay en `Datos`, puede que haya algún dato vacío ahí, o un dato que viole alguna restricción UNIQUE, de llave foránea, u otra en la base de datos. Sea como sea, tu código no debe ser mudo, sino capturar los errores e informar de algún modo. En fase de desarrollo, imprimiendo los mensajes de error podrás resolverlos rápidamente, y en fase de producción, informarás al usuario adecuadamente de eventuales errores. Ante un código mudo cuando hay error, el usuario le dará 500 veces al botón sin entender por qué no funciona, y optará por instalar un programa mejor escrito.

Comment: O, siendo que da un mensaje exitoso, puede que ¡no haya nada que actualizar! En algunos casos, una instrucción UPDATE que establece los mismos datos que ya tiene ese fila, es una instrucción exitosa en teoría, pero realmente no actualiza nada, ¡porque no hay nada que actualizar!. La forma de verificar un UPDATE es contando las filas actualizadas, no que la consulta sea exitosa.

Comment: Sumando a lo que dice Cedano, una consulta update exitosa podria tambien no afectar ninguna fila ya que ninguna cumpliria las condiciones del where.